# How to categorize and/or use keywords in Sharepoint Foundation 2010 wikis?

Tags: sharepoint, wiki, keyword, sharepointfoundation2010

We just installed Sharepoint Foundation 2010 and we're preparing to set it up for our knowledge management project.

I'm reading a lot over the Web and there seems to be options to categorize Wiki pages in Sharepoint, with the use of keywords and/or something called a "Term Store".

The problem is I can't find any of this in our installation of Sharepoint Foundation 2010.  My user is part of the Admin groups, but still I see lots of options greyed out and fields displayed on screenshots over the Web but not in our installation.

I'm a bit clueless since I don't find any info on my problem over the Web.

Thanks in advance.

Mark

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the **Document Library Settings** for the library that houses your wiki pages, you should see **Wiki Categories** as one of the metadata fields.  This is where the categories/keywords are stored for a particular page.  If you created an enterprise wiki site, on each wiki page you should be able to see on the right hand side an area called **Categories**.  This is the term store you're talking about.  If you have the wiki page in edit mode, you should be able to add categories (keywords, tags, whatever you want to call it) to the wiki page.

**If you don't see categories on the page...**

Categories, like the ratings area that should be above it, is a **web part**.   Pop the page into edit mode, go to *insert > web part* and then under the **Content Rollup** area, insert a new **Categories** web part.

Comment: As regards to your first paragraph (and based on all my readings over the Web), I think you're referring to another version of Sharepoint that the one I have (which is Sharepoint Foundation 2010). I don't see any of the options you're talking about and I know Enterprise Wiki Sites are not available in Foundation. For the second paragraph, under the Content Rollup area, I only have the following 2 options: Relevant Documents and XML Viewer. Thanks a lot for your help anyway. I'm still clueless about how Sharepoint Foundation 2010 is supposed to be and what's available in it.

Comment: Ahh, yea, I am running SharePoint Server 2010 with the Enterprise features turned on.  You can also go to the settings of your site collection and see if you can enable more options.  Other than that, I'm not sure that the categories for wiki pages is available in SharePoint Foundation.  :-/

Answer (score 1):

I've found a way using custom columns: I created a custom Category column under the following :

Site Settings --> Site Content Types --> Wiki Page

After, I can create a new site page and when I go edit its properties, I can add categories.

Answer (score 0):

We are running SharePoint 2010 Foundation and I just found I could add a "Category" column by doing these steps.

1. "View all Site Content".
2. Open the wiki in the list of "Document Libraries".
3. Under "Settings", choose "Document Library Settings".
4. Under "Columns", choose "Add from existing site columns".
5. In "Available site columns", select "Category" and click "Add >" to move the choice to "Columns to add".
6. Click "Ok" to save.
7. Open the wiki, edit a page, and "Category" will appear under the Wiki Content input box to receive your input.
8. Save the wiki page and the Category input should be under the wiki page content.
9. Searching the site using any of the words or phrases in the Category returns the wiki page!